# jquery nestable return json in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, jquery-nestable

I am using [msurguy/laravel-shop-menu](https://github.com/msurguy/laravel-shop-menu) it resturn results as json while it return html resutls for my other models.

## screenshot

[image: one]

As you can see two of my menus working fine but one of them return as JSON.

> Codes are the same for all of them I'm just getting different class
> names in JavaScript code to divide them.

## Code

`Model`

```
public function buildMenu($menu, $parentid = 0) 
    { 
      $result = null;
      foreach($menu as $item) 
        if ($item->parent_id == $parentid) { 
          $result .= "<li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='{$item->order}' data-id='{$item->id}'>
          <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>
          </div>
          <div class='nested-list-content'>{$item->title}
            <div class='float-right'>
              <a href='/admin/menusnav/{$item->id}'>Edit</a> |
              <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='{$item->id}'>Delete</a>
            </div>
          </div>".$this->buildMenu($menu, $item->id) . "</li>"; 
        } 
      return $result ?  "\n<ol class=\"dd-list\">\n$result</ol>\n" : null; 
    }
    // Getter for the HTML menu builder
    public function getHTML($items)
    {
        return $this->buildMenu($items);
  }
```

`controller`

```
$navbars = NavbarMenu::orderby('order', 'asc')->get();
$navbar = new NavbarMenu;
$navbar = $navbar->getHTML($navbars);
```

`Blade`

```
<div class="dd navbarf" id="nestable">
{!! $navbar !!}
</div>
```

`Javascript`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $('.navbarf').nestable({
                dropCallback: function(details) {
                    
                var order = new Array();
                $("li[data-id='"+details.destId +"']").find('ol:first').children().each(function(index,elem) {
                    order[index] = $(elem).attr('data-id');
                });
                
                if (order.length === 0){
                    var rootOrder = new Array();
                    $("#nestable > ol > li").each(function(index,elem) {
                        rootOrder[index] = $(elem).attr('data-id');
                    });
                }
                var token = $('form').find( 'input[name=_token]' ).val();
                $.post('{{url("admin/menusnav/reorder/")}}', 
                    {
                        source : details.sourceId, 
                        destination: details.destId, 
                        order:JSON.stringify(order),
                        rootOrder:JSON.stringify(rootOrder),
                        _token: token 
                    },
                    function(data) {
                    // console.log('data '+data); 
                    })
                .done(function() { 
                    $( "#success-indicator1" ).fadeIn(100).delay(1000).fadeOut();
                })
                .fail(function() {  })
                .always(function() {  });
                }

            });
            //delete item
            $('.delete_toggle').each(function(index,elem) {
                $(elem).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#postvalue').attr('value',$(elem).attr('rel'));
                $('#deleteModal').modal('toggle');
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any idea?

## UPDATE

`dd($navbar);` in controller

```
"""
\n
<ol class="dd-list">\n
<li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='1' data-id='8'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Theravada\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/8'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='8'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div>\n
<ol class="dd-list">\n
<li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='1' data-id='14'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Ajahn\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/14'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='14'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='2' data-id='15'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Sayadaw\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/15'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='15'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='3' data-id='16'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>SN Goenka\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/16'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='16'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li></ol>\n
</li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='2' data-id='9'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Mahayana\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/9'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='9'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div>\n
<ol class="dd-list">\n
<li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='1' data-id='17'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Ven Chen Yen (Tzu Chi)\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/17'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='17'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='2' data-id='18'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Ven. Shen Yen (Chan/Chinese Zen)\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/18'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='18'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='3' data-id='19'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Thich Nhat Hanh (Plum Village)\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/19'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='19'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li></ol>\n
</li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='3' data-id='10'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Vajrayana\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/10'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='10'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div>\n
<ol class="dd-list">\n
<li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='1' data-id='20'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Nyingma\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/20'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='20'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='2' data-id='21'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Kadampa\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/21'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='21'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='3' data-id='22'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Kagyu\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/22'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='22'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='4' data-id='23'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Sakya\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/23'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='23'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='5' data-id='24'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Chod\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/24'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='24'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li></ol>\n
</li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='4' data-id='11'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Resources\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/11'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='11'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div>\n
<ol class="dd-list">\n
<li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='1' data-id='25'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Buku (books)\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/25'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='25'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='2' data-id='26'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Sutta / Sutra\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/26'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='26'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li></ol>\n
</li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='4' data-id='12'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>News & Events\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/12'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='12'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div>\n
<ol class="dd-list">\n
<li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='1' data-id='27'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Dhammatalk\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/27'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='27'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='2' data-id='28'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Retreat\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/28'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='28'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='3' data-id='29'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Workshop\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/29'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='29'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='4' data-id='30'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>Center\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/30'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='30'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li></ol>\n
</li><li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-order='6' data-id='13'>\n
\t      <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>\n
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>\n
\t      </div>\n
\t      <div class='nested-list-content'>About Us\n
\t        <div class='float-right'>\n
\t          <a href='/admin/menusnav/13'>Edit</a> |\n
\t          <a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='13'>Delete</a>\n
\t        </div>\n
\t      </div></li></ol>\n
"""
```

Comment: $parentid parameter will be zero in that case, that might be a reason ?

Comment: I'm not sure as i mentioned it's the same code for the other 2 models. there working

Comment: Have you dumped the $navbar in controller ? can you add that in above question please

Comment: sure...........

Comment: @SagarGautam updated.

Comment: Quite strange issue, everything looks fine but still you have problem. Is there any other variable with same name in the view ?

Comment: @SagarGautam you're a true life saver man <3 :))) I just changed the variable name and it's working fine now. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Congrats bro, sometime we make bloody mistakes and waste a lots of hours :D

Comment: that's true. please share it as answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: Okay as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the code you have mentioned seems correct and the way you have used the html variable in view is also correct.

Sometime same variable value is replaced by something else in the view that might cause value override. So change the `$navbar` variable by some other.

And that should work.